# Need treeview without dotted lines between plus and minus signs in jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, treeview

I am using http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/demo/index.html this treeview code.I need exactly like sample 4. But I dont want dotted lines between plus/minus signs. Please help me in solving this

Comment: There are 3 demo on the page so where is 'sample 4'. Just inspect the element, find its css class and use css to hide it or better visibility: hidden as display:none can disturb the alignment of levels.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line no. 39 in jquery.treeview.css with

```
.treeview li{
    background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

This will replace dots. Still you have to change the +/- image to get rid of the dots.

Hope this helps..